How to add support for DataSource interface
I am the author of a JDBC Driver that supports connecting via DriverManager to a database engine I created.
DriverManager has a getConnection() method that takes a connection string to connect to my DB.  Many customers have been using this successfully for many years.
I want to add support for the DataSource interface (to support WebSphere).  The DataSource interface has a getConnection() with no parameters and one with username/password.  But I don't see how the caller would pass a connection string to my driver using this interface (or any other parameters to specify which server to connect to).  I've tried to read the docs, and many online examples, but I have not found an answer.
For example, many of the examples use knowledge of the example implementation to call methods not in the DataSource interface for setting the URL.  But I'm not expecting IBM to recompile WebSphere with knowledge of my specific class.
Any other advice for getting my JDBC Driver to work with WebSphere would also be appreciated.

What database engine? What JDBC driver?

My database engine.  My JDBC Driver.  I'm the author.  I want my DB to work with WebSphere, which doesn't work with DriverManager.

You created a database? And you created a JDBC driver?

Yes.  And now I want to support WebSphere connecting to my DB using JDBC.

First I should point out WebSphere Liberty does support connections via DriverManager. See this knowledge center doc in which it refers to java.sql.Driver, which means using DriverManager.
Otherwise, if you are interested in traditional WebSphere Application Server, that does not have DriverManager or javax.sql.DataSource support and so you would need to provide an implementation of javax.sql.ConnectionPoolDataSource or javax.sql.XADataSource.
In both cases, Liberty and traditional, there is support for users supplying a set of custom data source properties as name/value pairs. WebSphere will locate the corresponding setter method on your data source implementation. For example, if someone configures a property named serverName with value of localhost and a property named databaseName with a value of exampledb as custom data source properties, then WebSphere will search your data source implementation class for methods named setServerName and setDatabaseName accepting 1 argument, and reflectively invoke them on an instance of your data source implementation class, with the specified values, which equates to something like,
yourConnectionPoolDataSource.setServerName("localhost");
yourConnectionPoolDataSource.setDatabaseName("exampledb");


Write a class:

Implement the methods required by the DataSource interface.
Implement accessor methods (getters/setters) for all the features specific to your particular database engine.

Your implementation could offer a constructor that takes your connection string as an argument.
You may want to peruse the source code from some of the many open-source implementations, such as Postgres, H2 (source), MySQL, etc. Of course, you must respect their licensing terms if copying/following their code.

Since these aren't in the DataSource interface, are there specific getters/setters I need to supply, or will any that I supply just be discovered?  I had previously looked at some of the open implementations, as you suggested, but this didn't answer the question at the beginning of this comment.

How would WebSphere, for example, know to call my constructor with a connection string parameter?  Or, is that just general advice that could be used by others who know they are dealing with my driver?
